# List of months in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to have a select form with a list of months but I can't seem to get it to post correctly.

form:

```
   class MonthForm(forms.Form):
        months = [('January','January'),
                  ('February','February'),
                  ('March','March'),
                  ('April','April'),
                  ('May','May'),
                  ('June','June'),
                  ('July','July'),
                  ('August','August'),
                  ('September','September'),
                  ('October','October'),
                  ('November','November'),
                  ('December','December'),]
        month = forms.ChoiceField(months)
```

view:

```
def table_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        month = MonthForm(request.POST).cleaned_data['month']
        print month
```

I keep getting this error:

```
'MonthForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cleaned_data` attribute is present only after the form has been validated with `is_valid()`.

Just change your code to

```
def table_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MonthForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print form.cleaned_data['month']
```

---

Internally, if any errors are detected, the `cleaned_data` attribute will be deleted (see `forms/forms.py` around line 270) and hence not accessible:

```
if self._errors:
    delattr(self, 'cleaned_data')
```

---

See also: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#processing-the-data-from-a-form

Comment: Interesting.  I guess I didn't really think about validation for a select box  Thanks